# How do I run an update query?

Tags: cakephp

UPDATE images SET is_primary = 0 WHERE event_id = $id

from events controller, where Event hasMany Image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->Event->Image->updateAll(array('is_primary'=>0), array('Event.id'=>$id));
```

[Check this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) and search for **updateAll**

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->Event->saveAll($this->data);
```

See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

and: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm

Alternatively, you can save the Event, then loop over and save each Image.

There is also the option of:

```
$this->Image->query("UPDATE images SET is_primary = 0 WHERE event_id = $id");
```

See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query